# cannot resolve com.android.support.design:

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I tried the solution given before in stack overflow for this question, but it didnt  worked... I am trying to use TextInputLayout for floating label, so I tried this code in gradle file

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

implementation 'com.adroid.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.design:28.0.0'
```

}

and added this snippet in build.gradle(project) ..

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven{
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

}

but i am getting the error failed to resolve com.android.support.design
I even tried with versions 26 and 25...
what can be the problem? and how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Change it:

`implementation 'com.android.support.design:28.0.0'` with it:

`implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'` and try again